# Mongoose, Add/Update data to a set of documents of a collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

Hello guys here's the situation of my problem:

My **`Categories`** model looks like this:

```
schema: {   
    _id: String,
    name: String,
    overview: String,
    courses: [
        {
            _id: String,
            name: String
        }
    ]
}
```

I have multiple categories recorded, in the above collection **`Categories`**

**WHAT I NEED**

I have an **[** array **]** of **`Categories._id`** like this:

```
[
  '5812f3cb04700f2563c0e56a',
  '5812f3ff04700f2563c0e56b',
  ...
]
```

All I want is to **`PUSH`** this object **`{_id:5812f3ff04700f2563c0e56b, name:'SOMETHING' }`** to all the documents listed in the **array** of **`_id`**

**WHAT I TRIED**

```
Categories.update({
        '_id': {
            $in : array_of_IDs
        } 
    },
    {
        $push :{
            'courses':{ _id: ret._id , name: ret.title }
        }
    }, function(err, respp){
        if(err) return res.negotiate(err);
        else{
            req.addFlash('success', 'Categories updated successfully.');
            return res.redirect('/new-course');
        }
    }
);
```

This above code is updating only one collection (the collection with 1st ID in the array of IDs)

Please help!

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can try using `multi: true` as option

```
Categories.update({
        '_id': {
            $in : array_of_IDs
        } 
    },
    {
        $push :{
            'courses':{ _id: ret._id , name: ret.title }
        }
    },{ multi: true }, function(err, respp){
        //....
    }
);
```